# The namespace or module 'XXXXX' is not defined, for a function parameter

Tags: function, variables, parameters, f#, namespaces

When attempting to rework a merge sort program, I implemented a `match with` statement within a function.

```
let rec merge (array : int[]) (chunkA : int[]) (chunkB : int[]) a b i =
    match a, b with
    | chunkA.Length, _ -> chunkB
    | _, chunkB.Length -> chunkA
    | _ when chunkB.[b] < chunkA.[a]
        -> array.[i] <- chunkB.[b]
           merge array chunkA chunkB a (b+1) (i+1)
    | _ -> array.[i] <- chunkA.[a]
           merge array chunkA chunkB (a+1) b (i+1)
```

However, Visual Studio threw the error:

```
The namespace or module 'chunkA' is not defined.
```

This is confusing, since `'chunkA'` had been stated within the function parameters.

In addition, I am rather new to F# and functional programming in general. If the structure or methodology in my code is not up to par, then please feel free to comment on this as well.

Also, if I'm being thick, please feel free to tell me that as well.

Many Thanks, Luke

Answer (score 3):

As John mentioned, you cannot directly pattern match a numerical value against another variable. The language of patterns allows only constants, constructors and a few other things.

You can write the code using `when` but then you do not really benefit from the `match` constrct in any way, because you only have conditions in `when` clauses. In that case, I'd go for plain old `if`, because it makes it more obvious what you are doing:

```
let rec merge (array : int[]) (chunkA : int[]) (chunkB : int[]) a b i =
    if a = chunkA.Length then chunkB
    elif b = chunkB.Length then chunkA
    elif chunkB.[b] < chunkA.[a] then
        array.[i] <- chunkB.[b]
        merge array chunkA chunkB a (b+1) (i+1)
    else 
        array.[i] <- chunkA.[a]
        merge array chunkA chunkB (a+1) b (i+1)
```

The `match` construct is very useful if you are pattern matching on more functional data structures - for example if you were writing `merge` on two lists (rather than arrays), then it would be a lot nicer with pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

When you use match, you need to use compile time constants.

Something like this is what you want

```
|aa,_ when aa=chunkA.Length -> ....
```